# Does tensorflow re-use nodes created with the same formulas?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have

```
wT = tf.transpose(w, perm=[0, 2, 1])
```

line in different places of my graph creating code and `w` is always the same.

Will `wT` also be the same?

Comment: For clarification, why do you use this assignment multiple times?

Comment: Are you assigning to `wT` every time, or various other variables? Edit: this makes the most sense but I don't want to assume

Comment: @ElliotRoberts no, I can assign differen variables each time.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: yes if `w` really never changes

---

**This bit you likely already know:**

With Tensorflow with Python (probably with everything but I only know python myself) you define the flow of tensors and then run the model to determine each tensor's value. When you define `wT` here, `wT` represents a tensor with the values of `w` transposed, but it's actual values are not determined when the interpreter reaches this line; this assignment is only defining the model.

---

**This bit might be useful:**

If you have multiple tensors assigned like this, their values will all depend on `w` so if `w` changes they will too, but if `w` *never* changes, their values would all be the same. Depending on your application it may be better to create new tensors each time.